# CreateFile() failed when opening device driver without UAC

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver, createfile

I'm now on analyzing device driver binary. I had wrote code like below:

```
CreateFileA("\\\\.\\device_name", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

What I got from CreateFileA() returns was INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE(0xFFFFFFFF), without UAC. When I run same code with UAC authenticated It works great, it gave me valid handle.

I've heard the permission for accessing device driver is decided by device type argument of IoCreateDevice(). I checked it but the driver type was FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN(0x22), It can be accessed by not only Administrator but also other users. but I failed.

thus I've got frustrated. Am I thinking wrong? Why did i fail on CreateFile()? Could anyone help me?

Thanks for reading. Have a good day.

Comment: GetLastError() said 5 to me, ACCESS DENIED

Comment: No, the permission for accessing a device is not (necessarily) determined by the device type.  The device driver can set whatever permissions it likes. If you're getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED that's a pretty good indications that the permissions on the device don't allow non-administrators to open it.

Comment: You can use winobj.exe to check the security of the device object. The "device_name" symbolic link should be in "\Global??" and should resolve to a device object in "\Device". More than likely this will confirm that only Administrators and SYSTEM can open the device with `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` access. Everyone else may effectively have only `GENERIC_READ` or `GENERIC_EXECUTE` access.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh, I've mislearned... I should check other element which determine the permission... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @eryksun What a great tool, winobj! I checked that device driver with winobj and I got that administrator is the only one who has permission to access. It seems and I guess permission for accessing device was determined while installation. I should search about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tested two sample drivers. both drivers seem having same acl in winobj. but one driver can be opened by CreateFile() by Non-administrator, another driver can't be opened... both drivers also exist in '\GLOBAL??'